# XMLHttpRequest и обновление страницы

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, вёрстка, history-api

На главной страницы при клике подгружается html код при помощи XMLHttpRequest и изменяется url адрес с помощью history.pushState. Если человек нажимает обновить страницу, то страница ломается. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Для таких целей лучше уже строить SPA (Single Page Application) на Angular или React. Тогда у Вас будет и routing, и вложенные ui-view и много другого. Тогда не придется беспокоиться о плохом коде.

Comment: Реализовать что?
Когда пользователь обновляет страницу после того, как адрес изменился, то запрос уходит на новый адрес. Ваш web-сервер должен быть соответственно настроен.

Comment: Можно немного поподробне насчетAngular или React?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть url изменять при помощи `window.location.replace()`?

Comment: Можно поподробнее